# Can't boot into other OS after installing Ubuntu Budgie 21.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

My previous Ubuntu install was bloated with too many useless packages so I decided to reinstall and since I wanted to give Budgie a try, I installed it. However, upon reboot while everything works fine on Ubuntu, I cannot access my Archcraft install (which is detected by GRUB correctly, there is a boot entry but it boots into a black screen and I have to manually reboot. I ran boot repair, but it didn't help.

Ubuntu patebins for boot-repair: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/B2QSHZQnbK/ https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/GVBSVpJrQf/

Comment: Grub can only boot working OSes. Does Archcraft boot correctly on its own? If so please boot it, install any pending updates then change the boot back to Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: It used to boot correctly before I installed Ubuntu Budgie 21.04. But now it doesn't

Comment: Is it on a different partition from Ubuntu? If you installed Ubuntu to a different partition it would not affect any other partition except ESP which should not affect other installed operating systems. It's not clear that Ubuntu has anything to do with your problems in Arch. Maybe you should do more info gathering on your problems with your other installation and ask about this on https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes, they are installed on different partitions. I dont think it has anything to do with Ubuntu per se, but the issues only started after I reinstalled.

Comment: *It used to boot correctly before (...)* is irrelevant. Please proceed as requested above and post back results.

Comment: The thing is, I have no idea how I can boot into it since GRUB isn't working.

Comment: You show UEFI boot entry. Can you not boot it directly from UEFI boot menu entry?

Comment: I can still access the firmware settings yes, it's just Archcraft that won't boot anymore. Even Windows will boot normally. Honestly at this point I'll just reinstall and hope for the best.

Comment: Final update: took the lazy route, reinstalled both systems and now they work again. Thanks everyone for the answers, I greatly appreciate it.